# PDO and Microsoft SQL: Must declare the table variable "@P1"

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, pdo, parameterized

I'm trying to use binding in PDO to select some entries from a Microsoft SQL database. The code I'm using looks like it's similar to what I've found in the documentation. However, when I run it, I get the warning below:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1087 [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@P1". (SQLExecute[1087] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:254) in (long file path) on line 40

Here's the relevant code:

```
$table = "[User Site]";
$user = "demo";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ? WHERE user='?'"; 
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(1,  $table, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(2, $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute(); //                         <-- line 40
$data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This may be related. When I try to use named parameter markers (:table, :user) instead of question marks, I get this:

> Warning: PDOStatement::bindValue() [pdostatement.bindvalue]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in (long file path) on line 39

Why doesn't it like my prepared statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't bind parameters to table names in SQL.  This is true in any language, any database.

You'll have to interpolate the table name into the query string before `prepare()`.

Also you shouldn't put the parameter placeholder inside quotes, even if it's a string or date value.  Parameter placeholders inside quotes are interpreted as literal strings.  Otherwise how would you ever enter a literal question mark?

Here's how I would write this:

```
$table = "[User Site]";
$user = "demo";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user=?"; 
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array($user));
$data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I don't bother with using `bindParam()` or `bindValue()`. It's usually easier to just pass the parameter values in an array argument to `execute()`.