# Remove a row in an arbitrary table using data from a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called "changes" which contains a list of record numbers the user has modified on many other tables. I'd like to remove the record referenced by a row in changes (and the changes row itself) in one SQL query.

```
WITH name AS ( SELECT tableName FROM [changes] WHERE id = 80 ),
   number AS ( SELECT  changeRecnum FROM [changes] WHERE id = 80 )

DELETE FROM [name] WHERE changeRecnum = number

DELETE FROM [changes] WHERE id = 80
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting errors about how 'changeRecnum' and 'number' are invalid column names.

Comment: Apparently [my memory is awful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320320/pdo-and-microsoft-sql-must-declare-the-table-variable-p1).

You cannot use a parameter as a table name. Does WITH count as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic SQL to use a variable as a table name.  Best way I think would be to set your name and number as @variables.

```
DECLARE @name varchar(100)
DECLARE @number int
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

SET @name = (SELECT tableName FROM [changes] WHERE id = 80)
SET @number = ( SELECT  changeRecnum FROM [changes] WHERE id = 80 )

SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM [' + @name + '] WHERE changerecnum = ' + CAST(@number as varchar)
PRINT (@SQL)
EXEC (@SQL)

DELETE FROM [changes] WHERE id = 80
```

You need to read [this article about Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) though.  It's bascially required reading for these scenarios.